# Object.Create with Object.create(name) vs Object.create(name.prototype)

Tags: javascript

im learning javascript and im trying to understand the key differences.
I can create object with `Object.create(someName)` and I can create with
`Object.create(someName.prototype)` but i dont quite understand the key differences.
Should i put properties as regular properties?
like `someName.a` or `someName.prototype.a` ?
Its just little bit confusing for me.
I understand that when using `Object.Create` im defining my object prototype chain with the object im specifing but i can specify either `someName` or `someName.prototype` but i cant seem to fully understand the differences and best practice.
Thank you very much for your help.
:)

Comment: `someName` refers to one object, and `someName.prototype` refers to another object, so which one you should use with `Object.create()` really depends on what you are trying to achieve. Similarly, choosing between `someName.a` or `someName.prototype.a` depends on what you are trying to achieve - if you add a property to the prototype then *all* objects with that prototype will have access to it, which is helpful sometimes and unhelpful other times.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.create` creates a new object whose prototype is the one passed as the first argument of the whole function.

In JavaScript, the `prototype` property is a regular object with *special powers*, but as I've already said, it's still a *regular object*.

Therefore, the question of *when to go with x or x.prototype* depends on your requirements.

For example:

```
var obj = { name: "Matías" };

// This will create a new object whose prototype
// is the object contained in the "obj" variable
var obj2 = Object.create(obj);
```

In fact, an object doesn't own a `prototype` property. You use the other approach when you want to create an object from some constructor function's prototype:

```
var A = function() {};
A.prototype.doStuff = () => {
    // do stuff here
};

// A common mistake is to provide A instead of A.prototype.
// In JavaScript, even functions are objects, hence if you provide
// A instead of A.prototype, the prototype of the newly created object
// will be the function A and its members, not the ones that would be available
// creating an object like this: new A()
var B = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.doStuff();

var C = Object.create(A);
// Function "doStuff" is undefined!!
C.doStuff();
```